# arduino, RF24, NRF24l01 automatic radio number assignation (address number)

Tags: arduino, radio-transmission

I use NRF24L01 chip to communicate between 2 arduino.

I use "[GettingStarted_HandlingData](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/examples/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.ino)" as a base for most of my project.

is there a way to set automatically the address number [on line 23](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/examples/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.ino#L23) ?
To goal of this is to have only 1 file, 1 compilation then upload it to my 2 arduinos.